# Помогите понять из-за чего Python не видит файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

```python
import telegram_send
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class FileChangeEventHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, patterns=None, ignore_patterns=None, case_sensitive=False):
        super().__init__(
            patterns=patterns,
            ignore_patterns=ignore_patterns,
            ignore_directories=True,
            case_sensitive=case_sensitive
        )
    
    def on_modified(self, event):
        with open(event.src_path) as modifiedFile:
            for line in modifiedFile: pass
            print(line), telegram_send.send(messages=[line.strip()])

targetDir = r"C:\Users\kolmo\Desktop\idleServer\server_csgo\csgo\addons\sourcemod\logs\DropsSummoner.log"
patterns = ("test.txt", "DropsSummoner.log")

observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(
    event_handler = FileChangeEventHandler(patterns=patterns), 
    path = targetDir,
    recursive = False
)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopping")
finally:
    observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Этот код должен отслеживать файл DropsSummoner.log и после каждого его изменения выводить последнюю строку в консоль, но он не видит файл. Когда файл находится в папке с проектом, то все работает, а если файл находится в другой папке, то ничего не работает(

Comment: у вас переменная называется targetDir , а значение включает имя файла - это правильно?

Comment: @splash58 да, правильно

Comment: @splash58 так почему у меня файл не отслеживается, я не могу понять?)